# Finding values in consecutive rows

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

An example of the dataframe I have is given below.

```
ID     X      
1      1     
2      2      
3      1      
4      0      
5      0      
6      1      
7      4
8      5 
9      6
10     7
11     0 
12     0
```

I want to apply logic to it that looks to see whether 3 or more consecutive rows have a value >0 in it. If they do I want to flag them in another column. Hence the output will look as follows.

```
ID     X      Y
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      1      1
4      0      0
5      0      0
6      1      1
7      4      1
8      5      1
9      6      1
10     7      1
11     0      0
12     0      0
```

EXTENSION - 
How would I get the following output, givibng a different Y value for each group?

```
ID     X      Y
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      1      1
4      0      0
5      0      0
6      1      2
7      4      2
8      5      2
9      6      2
10     7      2
11     0      0
12     0      0
```

Answer (score 5):

One option with `base R`.  Using `rle` to find the adjacent values in 'X' that are greater than 0, then do the `rep`lication based on the `lengths`

```
df1$Y <- with(rle(df1$X > 0), as.integer(rep(values & lengths > 2, lengths)))
df1$Y
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

For the updated case in the OP's post

```
df1$Y <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$X > 0), {
             i1 <- values & (lengths > 2)
      values[i1] <- seq_along(values[i1])}))
df1$Y
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0
```

---

Or using `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Y := as.integer((.N > 2) * (X > 0)),rleid(X > 0)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:12, X = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
 6L, 7L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
 ))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create groups and use it in `ave` and get `length` of each group and assign 1 to groups which has length greater than equal to 3.

```
library(data.table)
df$Y <- as.integer(ave(df$X, rleid(df$X > 0), FUN = length) >= 3)

df
#   ID X Y
#1   1 1 1
#2   2 2 1
#3   3 1 1
#4   4 0 0
#5   5 0 0
#6   6 1 1
#7   7 4 1
#8   8 5 1
#9   9 6 1
#10 10 7 1
#11 11 0 0
#12 12 0 0
```

---

**EDIT**

For updated post we could include the above `data.table` part with `dplyr` by doing

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(group = rleid(X > 0)) %>%
  mutate(Y = ifelse(n() >= 3 & row_number() == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Y = cumsum(Y) * Y) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(Y = first(Y)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)


#     ID     X     Y
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     2     2     1
# 3     3     1     1
# 4     4     0     0
# 5     5     0     0
# 6     6     1     2
# 7     7     4     2
# 8     8     5     2
# 9     9     6     2
#10    10     7     2
#11    11     0     0
#12    12     0     0
```

Comment: why not go pure `data.table` with `df[, Y := as.integer(.N >= 3L), by = rleid(X > 0)]`

Comment: @snoram Thanks, I don't really use `data.table` so I am not much aware about the syntax but certain functions in `data.table` are really handy like `rleid`, hence preferred `ave`.